# Infer capture fails with Maven, succeeds without fork, but can't analyze

Tags: java, maven, facebook-infer

I am trying to perform static analysis of a Java project for null dereference errors using Facebook Infer, while using Maven to build the project and perform unit tests.
Here's the part of `pom.xml` that is responsible for working with Infer:

```xml
<profile>
   <id>infer-capture</id>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <verbose>true</verbose>
               <fork>true</fork>
               <executable>/PATH/TO/INFER/infer</executable>
               <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</profile>
```

Here's my status quo:

- When I run `mvn clean test`, everything builds and tests successfully.
- When I run `infer capture -- mvn clean test` with this project, I get a `MojoFailureException`.
- When I comment out the `<fork>true</fork>` line, the capture process terminates successfully. However, when I run `infer analyze` afterwards, I get "Nothing to analyze."
- When I run `infer capture -- mvn clean test --fail-never` and analyze the project, only about a quarter of all source files is analyzed.

As this is my first time working with Infer, I can't seem to grasp what is causing this issue.
The above `pom.xml` snippet is used in many other projects and never caused an error.
I'm especially frustrated because the `MojoFailureException` basically tells me nothing about the root cause.

Any suggestions for the root cause and/or solutions would be grateful.